# Algorithmic trading for perfect timing. I want to make a order at exact time 11:00:00

Tags: stock, algorithmic-trading

This is site for trading which is will be blur before the market open.
Now My aim to make a exact timing using algorithm or any other way.
For example, If my market open at 11:00:00. Then how can I make a order at the same exact time.
[image]

Comment: Did you look at site featured, maybe they have already this functionality ? If not then are ways, but maybe not so trivial. (they should have at least api to connect with and place your order through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this aspect is through api-s provided. Any decent trade platform should provide.

You could do an implementation with `php` and `curl` to place orders (and if api do not have a start date and is based on system time then schedule with `cron`).

Without any api you could try with some testing tools (`Selenium with java`) and maybe use a scheduler.Since you have to pass trough all `clicks` till reach `place order`, maybe it's better to schedule sooner all the action and wait till start time and then `simulate place order by click`